# PHP passing a variable to array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

This code works but `$vars` can't be defined in the `call()` function.
Why do `$vars` can't be passed to the `array_walk_recursive()`?

```
class lib{

    private $library;

    function __construct($lib="")
    {
        $this->library = $lib;
    }
    function set($vars)
    {
        $decoded_classes = json_decode($this->library,true);
        array_walk_recursive($decoded_classes,function(&$f) {$f = create_function($vars,$f);});
        return $decoded_classes;
    }
}
$json = '
{     
    "class1": {     
        "function1":"return \"$a<b>$b</b>!\";"
    },
    "class2": {     
        "function2":"return $b;",
        "function3":"return $c;"
    },
    "function1":"return \"test\";"
}';
$lib = new lib($json);
$lib = $lib->set("$a,$b");
$lib = $lib["class1"]["function1"]("asdasasd","asdasasd");
echo $lib;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, have a look at [this example with variable scoping for closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-163). You need to pass the variable in with the `use` keyword, eg:

```
array_walk_recursive($decoded_classes,function(&$f) use ($vars) {$f = create_function($vars,$f);});
```

It would be good if you defined `$a`, `$b`, etc for us, so we could actually test your code.

Comment: This answer was of limited help for the OP here, the code just went into an additional question: [PHP, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425559/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function). Users finding it here might be also interested in learning about that.