# PHP, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, php

```
class test
{
    public $do;
    function __construct($data="")
    {
        $this->parse($data);
    }
    private function parse($data)
    {
        // Decoding the functions
        $decoded_data = json_decode($data,true); 
        array_walk_recursive($decoded_data,function(&$function) {
            $first_line = strtok($function, "\n");
            preg_match("/\/\*#(.*?)\#*\//",$first_line,$matches);
            $function = create_function($matches[1],$function);
        });
        $this->do = $decoded_data;  
    }
}
```

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

The error is in:

`array_walk_recursive($decoded_data,function(&$function)`

Comment: Can you ensure that the code above is pasted exactly as it exists in your file? Start the copy/paste from the VERY first line: <?php...

Comment: Just as well to call out the line... thanks!

Comment: you can usually get very relevant results by googling the php error messages, and this is true here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your PHP version, anonymous functions are only supported on 5.3+

Comment: i think `array_walk_recursive` supported in PHP5

Comment: I had a similar problem, changed PHP version to 5.4. Means `mysql` will be deprecated, so you have to use `mysqli` or `PDO`